# Can this expression be made into a quadratic form?

Tags: quadratic-forms, homogeneous-equation

Can this expression be made into a quadratic form:

$ a x_t -\gamma {x_t}^2 $

I want to solve a linear quadratic programming problem and it requires that I put this expression in a quadratic form.

$ \gamma $ and *a* are parameters, scalars.

Comment: Who are $a$, $\gamma$, $x_t$, vectors, reals, other? Please provide us more information.

Comment: It is a quadratic if $\gamma\ne 0$.  If you want it to look more quadratic, complete the square.

Comment: I find the wording here is somewhat ambiguous, but the expression does not define a quadratic form in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form .

Comment: Yeah, it is not homogeneous. If I could "homogenize" this expression then perhaps I could express it as a quadratic form.

Answer (score 1):

The best I get:
$$ \alpha x_t - \gamma x_t^2 =  \begin{bmatrix} x_t \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} -\gamma & \frac{\alpha}{2} \\ \frac{\alpha}{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_t \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
az - b z^2
&=-b(z^2-(a/b)z)\\
&=-b(z^2-(a/b)z + (a^2/(4b^2)))-(a^2/4b)\\
&=-b(z-a/(2b))^2-(a^2/4b)\\
\end{array}
$

Is this what you want,
or have I misunderstood?

Comment: This would be completing the square. I actually was wondering if that expression I have, which is not homogenous, can be made into a quadratic form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form